# Sampling an inequality over multi-dimensional space

Tags: sampling

Let's say I have two functions $f(x,y,z), g(x,y,z)$. I would like to know the probability that $f(x,y,z) < g(x,y,z)$ over some defined, numerical ranges of $x, y, z$.

Any thoughts on how to do it besides nested for-loops?

P.S. I have more than 3 variables, but for simplicity let's assume I only have $x,y,z$.

Edit:

```
dL = 1; rL = 1; c = 0; 
f[dH_, rH_, α_, β_, γ_, 
   b_] := -(1/
     2) (-1 + β) Sqrt[-(((-1 + α) (dH (-1 + β) - \
β (1 + rH γ)^2))/(b^2 dH (-1 + β)))] + 
   1/2 β Sqrt[(α (dH - 
       dH β + β (1 + rH γ)^2))/(
    b^2 dH^2 β)];
g[dH_, rH_, α_, β_, γ_, b_] := 1/(
  2 (b + b (-1 + dH) β));

reg1 = ImplicitRegion[
   0 <= α <= 1 && 0 <= β <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1 && 
    0 <= γ <= 1 && 1 <= dH <= 5 && 1 <= rH <= 5, {dH, 
    rH, α, β, γ, b}];

reg2 = ImplicitRegion[
   f[dH, rH, α, β, γ, b] > 
     g[dH, rH, α, β, γ, b] && 0 <= α <= 1 &&
     0 <= β <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1 && 0 <= γ <= 1 && 
    1 <= dH <= 5 && 1 <= rH <= 5, {dH, 
    rH, α, β, γ, b}];

prob = RegionMeasure[reg2]/RegionMeasure[reg1] // N (* Takes forever to calculate RegionMeasure[reg2] *)

NIntegrate[1, {dH, rH, α, β, γ, b} ∈ 
  reg1] (* 16 *)

NIntegrate[1, {dH, rH, α, β, γ, b} ∈ 
  reg2, Method -> "AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo"] (* returns the function call. *)
```

Comment: You can either use something like `Integrate[Boole[inequalities], {x, ...}, ...]` or `reg = ImplicitRegion[inequalities, {x, y, z}]; Integrate[1, {x, y, z} \[Element] reg]`. An example of your inequalities would help.

Comment: There are "MonteCarlo" and  "AdaptiveMonteCarlo" integration strategies for `NIntegrate`. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html The Probability is equal to the volume $\Omega_{f<g}$ divided by the total volume $\Omega$, that is $p=\Omega_{f<g}/\Omega$, where $\Omega$ can be expressed as a multi- (3 in your example) dimensional integral.

Comment: @JohnSmith The best integration scheme depends mostly on the exact dimension and the complexity of your functions. If either the dimension is >=8 or there is no big chance that the integrals can be done analytically (via cylindrical algebraic decomposition), `AdaptiveMonteCarlo` and `AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo` are good `NIntegrate` `Method`s to try (see CarlWolls comment above).

Comment: Hi guys, thanks so much for the suggestions! I've tried `NIntegrate` with `AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo`, `AdaptiveMonteCarlo`, `MonteCarlo` but with no luck. Mathematica just returns the function call. I'll update the question with specific inequalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** With your function `f` and `g` we van calculate probability of `f>g` in the domain as:

```
      dL = 1; rL = 1; c = 0;
f[dH_, rH_, α_, β_, γ_, 
   b_] := -(1/
       2) (-1 + β) Sqrt[-(((-1 + α) (dH (-1 + β) - \
β (1 + rH γ)^2))/(b^2 dH (-1 + β)))] + 
   1/2 β Sqrt[(α (dH - 
          dH β + β (1 + 
              rH γ)^2))/(b^2 dH^2 β)];
        g[dH_, rH_, α_, β_, γ_, b_] :=  1/(2 (b + b (-1 + dH) β));

n = 100000;
{dH, rH} = RandomReal[{1, 5}, {2, n}];
{α, β, γ, b} = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4, n}];
pts = Transpose[{dH, rH, α, β, γ, b}];
Total@UnitStep[f @@@ pts - g @@@ pts]/n // N
```

> 0.85568

**Original Answer:**
How about this?

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x + y + z
g[x_, y_, z_] := 2 x + 2 y + 2 z

n = 1000000;

{aX, bX} = {-5, 5};
{aY, bY} = {-3, 6};
{aZ, bZ} = {2, 7};
rangeX = RandomReal[{aX, bX}, n];
rangeY = RandomReal[{aY, bY}, n];
rangeZ = RandomReal[{aZ, bZ}, n];

pts = Transpose[{rangeX, rangeY, rangeZ}];

Total@UnitStep[g @@@ pts - f @@@ pts]/n // N
```

> 0.920215

Comment: Thanks! This will work no matter how complex the inequalities are.

Answer (score 3):

Using the functions provided by OkkesDulgerci

```
Clear["Global`*"];

f[x_, y_, z_] := x + y + z;
g[x_, y_, z_] := 2 x + 2 y + 2 z;

{aX, bX} = {-5, 5};
{aY, bY} = {-3, 6};
{aZ, bZ} = {2, 7};

reg1 = ImplicitRegion[
   aX <= x <= bX && aY <= y <= bY && aZ <= z <= bZ, {x, y, z}];

reg2 = ImplicitRegion[
   f[x, y, z] < g[x, y, z] &&
    aX <= x <= bX && aY <= y <= bY && 
    aZ <= z <= bZ, {x, y, z}];

prob = Volume[reg2]/Volume[reg1] // N

(* 0.92037 *)
```

or

```
prob = RegionMeasure[reg2]/RegionMeasure[reg1] // N

(* 0.92037 *)
```

The region is

```
RegionPlot3D[f[x, y, z] < g[x, y, z],
 {x, aX, bX}, {y, aY, bY}, {z, aZ, bZ},
 BoxRatios -> {bX - aX, bY - aY, bZ - aZ},
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.75]]
```

[image]